# iPhone Mic volume

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, audio, avfoundation

Is there any way to poll the mic input volume with AVFoundation? I have seen the CoreAudio examples like SpeakHere but I really only need the current value. Is CA my only option?

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout SCListener. It's a simple way just to get the average or peak level of the mic.

http://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener